# ERROR org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder - ORM Mapping Invalid and others

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, orm

running an app created in 2.2.2 on 3.1.2 of grails and receiving a lot of errors. I'm new with grails and I am very confused with the errors emerging.

```
ERROR org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateMappingBuilder - ORM Mapping Invalid: Specified config option [permissions] does not exist for class [class.User]!

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jasper/runtime/JspFactoryImpl

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_65]

ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Servlet [jsp] in web application [] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl
```

those are bits and pieces, the whole error message is very long

user.groovy

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils;

class User {
    String username
    String password
    String permissions
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String email
    String department

    static hasMany = [updates: Update]

    static constraints = {
        username (blank:false)
        password (blank:false)
        firstName (blank:false)
        lastName (blank:false)
        permissions()
        email()
        department()
    }

    String toString() {
        username
    }

    static String hashPassword(String password) {
        DigestUtils.shaHex(password)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ORM Mapping Solution
https://github.com/sergiomichels/grails-doc/commit/aad7352f1af3b5c1db91705936d19b546dabb872

credits to her

Answer (score 0):

You can't run an app created in one version of Grails on another. Grails is *very* anal about using the correct version. To run that 2.2.3 app on 3.1.2 you need to upgrade the app to use 3.1.2. See https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/upgrading.html

Comment: You have to options: Either upgrade the app to Grails 3.1.2, or leave it as-is and run it using Grails 2.2.2. The latter is the quickest way to get it up and running. As the saying goes, *you can't have your cake and eat it too*.

Comment: i did try, it's a lot worse than migrating. for example  Error java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExceptionm.JVM copyField
| Error         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  | Error Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getAt() on null object
| Error         at grails.util.BuildSettings.configureDependencyManager(BuildSettings.groovy:1257)

Comment: SEVERE: Problems copying field. Incompatible JVM?
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   -   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not copy a non-root Field
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.copy(Field.java:148)

Comment: Something is certainly out of whack. If you create a brand new dummy Grails 2.2.2 app, with nothing in it except the defaults, does it run successfully?

Comment: that's the thing, that error came out without anything in it, that's just the base file i downloaded

Comment: What do you mean by *base file*?

Comment: i mean newly extracted, just downloaded grails 2.2.2.zip, placed it in a folder, that's it, ran it and behold the errors

Comment: OK let's back up. There are more reliable ways to install Grails. On Windows there's Posh GVM and for everything else, there's SDKman. The problem right now is that you don't have a working Grails environment. So try installing Grails with one of the aforementioned tools.

Answer (score 0):

> ORM Mapping Invalid: Specified config option [permissions] does not
>   exist for class [class.User]

This means that you are trying to call `class.User`'s parameter `permissions` which does not exist.

Comment: but it does exist though, static constraints = {
  username blank:false
  password blank:false
  firstName blank:false
  lastName blank:false
  permissions()
  email()
  department()
 }

Comment: These are just constraints. Add to your question full domain class `class.User` code, please.